# Refreshing an Excel Pivot Table data source with VBA in MS Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, pivot-table

I prefer producing an Excel report that has no links in it, so that it is lightweight and can easily be emailed.

So I have this report that I generate from MS Access - it writes the table to the TAB of a workbook that I have previously built a Pivot Table that uses that tab as it's source.

What I can't seem to get working properly is

```
xlPivot.PivotTables("pvAFP").RefreshTable
```

My code is as follows:

```
Public Sub ViewAFP(strPathToTemplate As String, Optional dbFullPath As String)

'10 Excel objects created
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim WB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim xlPivot As Object
Dim rngWorkingRange As Object
Dim intCOL As Integer

Dim db As Database

Dim rsAFP_Pivot As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsAFP_Data As DAO.Recordset



Dim fld As Variant

Dim strLocation As String


'uses the 'My Documents\COB folder of the user
'C:\Users\[username]\Documents\COB
strLocation = "C:\users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Documents\COB\AFP_Summary_" & DateString & ".xlsx"



Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set WB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPathToTemplate)

Set xlSheet = WB.Sheets("AFP DATA")
Set xlPivot = WB.Sheets("AFP PIVOT")



'ALLOW FOR EXTERNAL ENGINES
If Len(dbFullPath) < 1 Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
Else
    Set db = OpenDatabase(dbFullPath, True)
End If


Set rsAFP_Data = db.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM AFP_DATA")

intCOL = 1

For Each fld In rsAFP_Data.Fields
    xlSheet.Cells(1, intCOL).Value = fld.Name
    Debug.Print fld.Name
    intCOL = intCOL + 1
Next


xlSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsAFP_Data


Set rngWorkingRange = xlSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion


    xlSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngWorkingRange, , xlYes).Name _
        = "AFP_Data"
    xlSheet.ListObjects("AFP_Data").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

'set pvAFP to point to this table
    xlPivot.PivotTables("pvAFP").ChangePivotCache WB.PivotCaches. _
        Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="AFP DATA!AFP_Data", _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)



xlPivot.Select

xlPivot.PivotTables("pvAFP").RefreshTable

WB.RefreshAll
WB.SaveAs FileName:=strLocation

xlApp.Quit

Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing

Set rsAFP_Data = Nothing

Set db = Nothing
Set WB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Would be nice to be ready to use, because the user needs to "Refresh ALL", before anything can be done to the Pivot Table

Comment: First, storing data in Excel makes it heavier and not lightweight. Links are not data. You would see a noticeable difference in file size with an ODBC pivot table especially if table is in the thousands. Second, I see you use a template but nowhere do you delete previous data with `Range().Delete`. Also, consider refreshing the [PivotCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195521.aspx)

Comment: But what if you were regularly sending the file to someone who didn't have access to your network - or have the software or permission to design a Web page to give them access to?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
xlPivot.PivotTables("pvAFP").PivotCache.Refresh
```